# subsetting a dataset based on same conditions on a numbered list variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset at hand that looks like the following:

ID      MED1     MED2    MED3   MED4

1       892        384      454       345

2       802        394      434       233

3       852        384      334       599

I want to subset the dataset so that only patients who have been prescribed meds in code {892, 334, 599, 384} remains. I don't want to repeat the list of 4 codes in all 4 variables in the data step. Can anyone show me how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain why it is not what you want. Show how your MEDx variables are defined. Are they really numeric? Normally medication codes are strings.  Do you just want the list of distinct ID values?  Or do you want to find all records for the patients that ever had any of the med codes?  Or just the records that match the med codes and exclude other records for those patients?

Comment: They are numeric. It's data simulated by my professor for assignment. And yes I should have been more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I might be lazy and/or reading the question wrong, but I'd just use a macro variable and be done with it. Like so:

```
%let medcodes=892,334,599,384;

data want;
    set have;
    where MED1 in (&medcodes.) 
        or MED2 in (&medcodes.) 
        or MED3 in (&medcodes.)
        or MED4 in (&medcodes.);
run;
```

Not pretty, nothing fancy, wouldn't perhaps use it in some complicated production system, but for a one-off task does the job without getting overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one record per patient, you can do it using arrays

```
data patientMedsData;
    infile datalines delimiter=' ';
    input ID MED1 MED2 MED3 MED4;
    datalines;
1 892 384 454 345
2 802 394 434 233
3 852 384 334 599
;
run;


data result;
    set patientMedsData;
    array med [*] med1-med4;
    array prescribedMeds [4] _temporary_ (892, 334, 599, 384);

    retain keepPatient;
    drop keepPatient;
    * Reset the flag for each new record;
    keepPatient = 0;
    * Look for the prescribed meds;
    drop i j;
    do i = 1 to dim(med);
        do j = 1 to dim(prescribedMeds);
            if med[i] eq prescribedMeds[j] then do;
                keepPatient = 1;
                * Leave the loops as the med is found;
                i = dim(med) + 1;
                leave;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    * Filter patients without the prescribed meds;
    if keepPatient ne 1 then do;
        delete;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Medical codes typically have a limited domain.  For the case of a 3-digit code you can use direct address flagging:

```
data have;
input ID MED1 MED2 MED3 MED4;
datalines;
1 892 384 454 345
2 802 394 434 233
3 852 384 334 599
;

data want;
  set have;
  array flags (0:999) _temporary_;
  array vars med1-med4;
  do _n_ = 892, 334, 599, 384; flags(_n_) = 0; end;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(vars);     flags(vars(_n_)) = 1; end;
  do _n_ = 892, 334, 599, 384; flag_count=sum(flag_count, flags(_n_)); end;
  if flag_count > 0;  * adjust pass through threshold as needed;
run;
```

A more generic version would list the targets in an array instead of as a list of do loop indices:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array targets(4) _temporary_ (892, 334, 599, 384);
  array flags (0:999) _temporary_;
  array vars med1-med4;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(targets);  flags(targets(_n_)) = 0; end;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(vars);     flags(vars(_n_)) = 1; end;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(targets);  flag_count = sum(flag_count, flags(targets(_n_))); end;
  if flag_count > 0;  * adjust pass through threshold as needed;
run;
```